# How to create text in JavaScript After Effects?

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I tried to create text with `addText(text)`, but when I click on the execute button nothing happens.

Here are the lines of code

```
button6.onClick = function() {
    addText();

    function addText() {
        app.beginUndoGroup("My Process");
        var comp = app.project.activeItem;
        var selectedlayer = comp.selectedLayers[0];
        if (comp == null) {
            alert("No composition selected");
        }
        if (comp.selectedLayers[0] == null) {
            alert("Select the layer");
        }
        var outpoint = comp.selectedLayers[0].outPoint;
        var inpoint = comp.selectedLayers[0].inPoint;
        var duration = outpoint - inpoint;
        var textLayer = comp.layers.addText(text);
        var sourceText = textLayer.property("Source Text").value;
        sourceText.fontSize = 100;
        sourceText.font = Arial;
        textLayer.property("Source Text").setValue(sourceText);
        textLayer.adjustmentLayer = false;
        textLayer.inPoint = inpoint;
        textLayer.label = 1;
        comp.layer(1).moveBefore(selectedlayer);
        app.endUndoGroup();
    }
}
```

I tried to use `addBoxText(text)`, but result was the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the text variable is not defined in your code snippet, which may be causing the `addText()` function to fail. You need to pass the desired text as an argument to the `addText()` function. Here's how you can make it work:

```
button6.onClick = function() {
    var myText = "Hello, After Effects!"; // Replace this with the text you want to add

    addText(myText);

    function addText(text) {
        app.beginUndoGroup("My Process");
        var comp = app.project.activeItem;
        var selectedlayer = comp.selectedLayers[0];
        if (comp == null) {
            alert("No composition selected");
        }
        if (comp.selectedLayers[0] == null) {
            alert("Select the layer");
        }
        var outpoint = comp.selectedLayers[0].outPoint;
        var inpoint = comp.selectedLayers[0].inPoint;
        var duration = outpoint - inpoint;
        var textLayer = comp.layers.addText(text);
        var sourceText = textLayer.property("Source Text").value;
        sourceText.fontSize = 100;
        sourceText.font = "Arial";
        textLayer.property("Source Text").setValue(sourceText);
        textLayer.adjustmentLayer = false;
        textLayer.inPoint = inpoint;
        textLayer.label = 1;
        comp.layer(1).moveBefore(selectedlayer);
        app.endUndoGroup();
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, how to change duration of text?

Comment: Try this: var customDuration = 3; // Set the custom duration in seconds

Answer (score -1):

If you are using plain JavaScript, the event function name should be `onclick` instead of `onClick`.

Comment: other functions with onClick working fine, and if I do not select a layer, then it gives a warning that the layer is not selected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).